# How are Asura and rakshas so powerfull

Tags: vedas, dharma, brahmacharya

If it is said that seminal energy brings strength power and peace, then how are so many Asura and rakshas powerfull even more than god's if they don't follow celibacy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Asura and rakshas so powerfull](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57124/how-are-asura-and-rakshas-so-powerfull)